# Dompdf Laravel error sale una X Image not found or type unknow?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Cuando intento imprimir una imagen con Dompdf me lanza una X, si intento únicament [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el controlador para la descarga
        public function descargar($id, $if)
        {
             $recepcion = Recepcion::find($id);

```
        if ($if) {
              $pdf = \PDF::loadView('emails.descarga', compact("recepcion"));
return $pdf->stream();

        }else{
              $pdf = \PDF::loadView('emails.descarga', compact("recepcion"));
return $pdf->download('recepcion'.$recepcion->id.'.pdf');

        }

    }
```

Asi lo obtengo en la vista:
    $recepcion->imagen_golpes])}}">

Con esto obtengo la imagen

```
  public function getImage($filename)
    {
        $disk = "system";
        $fileSearch = "$filename";
        $file = Storage::disk($disk)->get($fileSearch);
        $fileHeader = Storage::disk($disk)->mimeType($fileSearch);
        return response($file, 200)->header('Content-Type', $fileHeader);
    }
```

Nota: Si intento imprimir unicamente la URL y luego la pongo en el navegador me devuelve normal la imagen.

Comment: Es una imagen .png? Probaste con una .jpg?

Comment: si he probado pero no funciona

Comment: Tienes instalada la librería [gd](https://www.php.net/manual/es/intro.image.php) (y sus dependencias)?